# Looking for a certain word from column A in column B

Tags: mysql

I've searched the web but I didn't find the right answer for me.

I have 2 tables with columns 'filename' in both of them.
Table 1 - Column A would have a file name, for example: dad.txt
Table 2 - Column A would have the full path of the file, for example: C:\example\dad.txt

I would like to run a query that would check the filenames from table 1 against all of the values in table 2 - column A (with the full path) and would show a match.

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: My result should be all of the data from Table 2 - Coulmn A that includes the filename from Table 1 - Coulmn A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it any problem if using "LIKE" syntax.

Try

```
WHERE table2.columnA LIKE CONCAT('%', table1.columnA)
```

Or try MATCH AGAINST syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Follow up question, will it work if I have a large numbe of data in Table 1 - Coulmn A and I don't know all of it? So I don't know where I have dad.txt in that column.

Comment: So, you would better use MATCH AGAINST syntax with proper constraint in your table schema.